# How to find which shared library started a thread

Tags: linux, multithreading, unix, shared-libraries

The question is in the subject. Let me explain "why".
I am running my application on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.7. When I was checking performance using htop I found that few threads take too much of the CPU.
I added some debug logging and found that the threads with high CPU are not created in my code. So I assume that these CPU greedy threads are created in 3rd party shared libs which I am using.
So there is a question:
Say I have a thread id (17405). Is there any way to find which shared lib started this thread?

I apologize if the question is too trivial - I started work with Linux OS not long time ago.

Thank you

Comment: Would [`ltrace`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html) help?

Comment: There's also [gstack](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gstack)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found solution which looks satisfactory to me.
I start gdb, attach to my process, then i can list all threads in the process "info threads", then i select thread I am interested in, and  - voila - i can see the stack trace by issuing bt command.
Works I think